# Reset timer on mousemove and keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

The below javascript code auto refresh the page every 10 sec.

My question is how can I reset the timer on mousemove and keypress.

**Java-Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

        var secs;
        var timerID = null;
        var timerRunning = false;
        var delay = 1000;

        function InitializeTimer(seconds) {
            //length of the timer, in seconds
            secs = seconds;
            StopTheClock();
            StartTheTimer();
        }

        function StopTheClock() {
            if (timerRunning)
                clearTimeout(timerID);
            timerRunning = false;
        }

        function StartTheTimer() {
            if (secs == 0) {
                StopTheClock();
                window.location.href = window.location.href;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("lbltime").innerText = secs + " ";
                secs = secs - 1;
                timerRunning = true;
                timerID = self.setTimeout("StartTheTimer()", delay);
            }
        }
</script>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: // in the example above, assign the result
var timeoutHandle = window.setTimeout(...);

// in your click function, call clearTimeout
window.clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);

// then call setTimeout again to reset the timer
timeoutHandle = window.setTimeout(...);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, something like this (really basic example: the timer is reset on mousemove and keypress):

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("timer"), timeout, startTimer = function timer() {
    elem.textContent++;
    timeout = setTimeout(timer, 1000)
}
function resetTimer() {
    // here you reset the timer...
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    elem.textContent = -1;
    startTimer();
    //... and also you could start again some other action
}
document.addEventListener("mousemove", resetTimer);
document.addEventListener("keypress", resetTimer);
startTimer();
```

```html
<span id="timer">-1</span> - Move cursor or press a key to reset timer.
```

As I guess, you want to delay page reloading if there was some user activity on the page. In your `reload()` function you just need to check, if timer's value reached the limit (like 60 seconds). If yes, execute reloading. However, notice, that handling `mousemove` event can make browser's tab have high CPU usage, if, for example, I just start to move my cursor quickly. You might want to pick some important areas and set handlers on the corresponding elements. For example, `keypress` event can be listened to only on a comment form or `mousemove` can be listened to only on a menu or on an article.

PS. Also take into account [that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress)

> The keypress event is fired when a key is pressed down, and that key normally produces a character value

so, if user presses, for example, `ctrl` or `alt` the event will not be fired.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems a bit too branched out in my opinion, what I would do is simplify it a bit.

```js
window.refreshTimeout = null;

function refreshPage(){
  location.reload();
}

function refresh(){
  clearTimeout(window.refreshTiemout);
  window.refreshTimeout = setTimeout(refreshPage, 2000)
}

window.refreshTimeout = setTimeout(refreshPage, 2000)
window.addEventListener('mousemove', refresh)
```

```html
<h4>HelloWorld</h4>
```

As you can see, you attach an event listener to the window for a mouse move (you can attach others too) within which you cancel the previous timeout and start a new one. Initially you of course start a timeout.